# How to make psql completion with Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql

There is a completion function by the psql command of Cygwin or UNIX
There is not the function in psql for a Windows native.
How to make psql completion with  Windows?
may be need readline!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readline is disabled by default on Windows. You can rebuild with it enabled - but it is broken for most non-english locales. For example, in most western european locales you can no longer type backslash - an essential character to use readline. This is a bug in readline, but last time I checked they had zero interest in the win32 platform and won't fix it.

Comment: Is the missing readline also the reason for the arrow up not working? I would expect arrow up to repeat the last input.